# Route IP traffic to different machines based on API call

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I have a requirement to route IP traffic on public IP a.b.c.d:xyz to either e.f.g.h:xyz or e.f.g.i:xyz, based upon some known state of those machines (known to my app). The traffic itself would not change, I simply want to be able to throw a software Frankenstein switch which send it to either server A or B. Obviously a.b.c.d:xyz would most likely be on a DSL router, so that would be forwarded to d.e.f.g:xyz would would then contain the putative routing application to forward to either a.b.c.d or e.f.g.h (with me so far?).

This is not a round-robiny type thing for a web server farm, it's so the maintainers can do their funky thing on a server and then enable it again later, and have the traffic silently routed around them, to a specific standby server. The API to throw the switch would have to be exposed as a C api, privilege is not an issue, we can write a service to do the switching if need be.

Is anyone aware of a routing application that exposes such an API? this would have to work for multiple ports and both TCP and UDP. Looking through the similar questions here, I couldn't see any that exactly matched the requirement.

Comment: If you're using a managed router you could send an updated configuration to it over TFTP or commands through telnet...

Comment: Sadly this is for multiple customers and I cannot know in advance what routers they'll be using. Often it's small SOHO ADSL types.

Comment: There might be an interface that you can send commands to.  Check with the manufacturer of the routers.  Also, why are these servers not configured so that if the primary is removed from the network, the secondary takes over?

Comment: We're already in the middle of making that change where possible :). Just looking for alternative approaches, and want to be able to cater for third party/old stuff which we can't alter.

Comment: Unfortunately, with amateur hardware there really isn't a one-size-fits-all solution.  This is your opportunity to sell some hardware!  You can get some really good, used Cisco managed routers for just a few hunderd bucks.

Comment: we're altering code for those few customers with kit and skills to route traffic to all machines (so the apps active state will be taken account of). the bulk of customers will only be able to route to one machine - which is where the proposed solutiomn would come in.